# Discrepencies in lengths of ints typecasted as strings

Tags: python, math, casting

I'm on Python 3.3.4

Why is the length of the product of two numbers correct but the length of the dividend of two numbers incorrect?

Example:

```
y = 10 / 2
len(str(y)) #outputs 3 (incorrect - should be 1)

y = 10 * 2
len(str(y)) #outputs 2 (correct)
```

Please forgive me if this is a dumb question.

Comment: Ahhh lol.  yeah that will do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
y = 10 / 2
print(y)
# 5.0
```

When you convert the number `5.0` to string, it has three characters. That is why the length of the number is 3.

If you are looking floor division, then you should be using `//`.

```
y = 10 // 2
print(y)
# 5
print(len(str(y)))
# 1
```

Timing comparison between both the methods

```
from timeit import timeit
print(timeit("len(str(int(10/2)))"))
# 0.3285439129685983
print(timeit("len(str(10//2))"))
# 0.2169595289742574
```

Comment: Which would be faster.  Typecasting the float as an int and then a str to check the length or flooring it with // ?  e.g. len(str(int(10/2)))

Comment: `//` would be the fastest here :)

Comment: @ColtonAllen Please check the timing comparison I included in the answer.

Comment: Its certainly more readable with //.  Thanks for the tidbit, I'll accept when stackoverflow lets me.  edit: thanks for the timing :)!!

Answer (score 0):

This would be ***far*** simpler if you would just print `y`.

Python 3 defaults to *true division* ([PEP 238](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/)), which essentially promotes everything to floating-point.

So `10 / 2` is `5.0` which, as a string, has three characters.